# Write a fabric file for rsync with a ssh key

Tags: python, ssh, rsync, fabric, private-key

I want to create a deploy task with a fabric file. We have some times only ftp data or ssh data.

This Code works

```
def sync_app():
 local("rsync -rtlv --delete dist/ server:%s" % code_dir)
```

But with this code every user must have the same ssh config file. So i want the data in the project. At this moment i dont know best practice but if i wrote manual the data in the code i get errors. What did i wrong?

```
def sync_app():
 local("rsync -rtlv --delete dist/ 'ssh -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa_dploy -p 9600' user@server:%s" % code_dir)
```

Comment: You could use the `-F` argument to `ssh` and point it to a temporary config file you create (maybe it ships with your project, then you copy it to /tmp/...) that's separate from the users'.

Answer (score 1):

Please post your errors, but I think your issue is being caused by a lack of use of the `-e` flag.  When using rsync over ssh use `-e`:

```
def sync_app():
 local("rsync -rtlv "
       "-e 'ssh -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa_dploy -p 9600' " 
       "--delete dist/ user@server:%s" % code_dir)
```

https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync :

```
-e, --rsh=COMMAND
    This option allows you to choose an alternative remote shell program to use for communication between the local and remote copies of rsync. Typically, rsync is configured to use ssh by default, but you may prefer to use rsh on a local network.
```

Comment: For me the following works: rsync -avz -e 'ssh -i /Users/username/.ssh/id_rsa_dploy -p 9600' <source> user@server:<destination>